# Authorization does not work properly in ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web-config, authorization

I have an ASP.NET application running on a server. I want to allow all members of Administrators group - which can be local users, or members of domain group(s) added to Administrators group. Administrators group has local users, as well as domain groups like DOMAIN\Domain Admins and DOMAIN\Local Admins. Below is a code I use in web.config for authorization.

```
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="BUILTIN\Administrators" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

I have domain account which is a member of DOMAIN\Domain Admins. When I RDP (using same domain account) into the server (where ASP.NET is running), and I try to open the website, I cannot login. However, when I access the ASP.NET website from a remote machine (using same domain account), I can log in - WHY?

Server is using Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Weird question, but potentially helpful... are you using localhost? Like the word "localhost" on the machine or is it bound to another name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using proper authorization xml definition in web.config:

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles="Administrators" />
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

BUILTIN\Administrators should be avoided as it does not accurately represent Local Administrators group - it has slightly high privileges than Administrators.
Also, i was denying all users, but should deny only anonymous users.